# How to delete rows one by one so that the trigger doesn't throw an error

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a trigger that when a row is deleted in InvoiceDetails the row gets copied to InvoiceDetailsHistory. When I execute the sql "DELETE FROM InvoiceDetails " I get an error that says:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

I supposed because I'm deleting the rows all at once. How could I fix this? Here's my trigger:

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[deleteinvoicedetails]       
on [dbo].[InvoiceDetails]
AFTER DELETE 
AS
DECLARE @InvoiceID int,@FoodID int,@quantity int,@UnitPrice float,@totalprice float
BEGIN
SET @InvoiceID = (Select InvoiceID from deleted)
SET @FoodID = (Select FoodID from deleted)
SET @quantity = (Select quantity from deleted)
SET @UnitPrice = (Select UnitPrice from deleted)
SET @totalprice = (Select totalprice from deleted)
INSERT INTO InvoiceDetailsHistory VALUES (@InvoiceID,@FoodID,@quantity,@UnitPrice,@totalprice)
END
```

Comment: Fix the trigger, not the `DELETE`. A DML statement can affect 1+ rows, your trigger, however, expects only 1 row, so doesn't behave as expected when there is more than 1. FIx the trigger, fix the problem. [Bad habits to kick : abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're clearly still learning, so let me give an example of what @tomtom is referring to...

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[deleteinvoicedetails]       
on [dbo].[InvoiceDetails]
AFTER DELETE 
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO
  InvoiceDetailsHistory
SELECT
  InvoiceID,
  FoodID, 
  Quantity,
  UnitPrice,
  Totalprice
FROM
  deleted
END
```

This works no matter how many rows are deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered fixing the trigger? This insert is abhorrent assuming that deleted is ONE row - which it may not be, and deleting rrows one by one will only make the problem hidden until it pops up.

The proper way is to:

- Get rid of all the variables. They make no sense.
- Use the Inser INTO .... SELCT syntax to select the deleted data and insert it into the invoice details history table. This will require bascially to use th deleted table as source (in the select part of insert into).

This will also be tremendously faster - you bascailyl run a lot of redundant operations one by one (set) instead of using SQL. Even if your code would not be broken (one row) all the SET could be done in ONE select. You can select into variables, and do so multiple variables at the same time.

But really, in your case the variables make no sense. You can directly insert into the history table by selcting the data from the deleted table.